# How to change MacBook 16" M1 resolution to 1920x1080p?

Tags: macbook-pro, resolution

I need to record screencast HD 1920x1080 videos but I can't find a way to set the builtin laptop screen resolution to those dimensions. It can be done on an Intel MacBook 16" 2019 using software such as SwitchResX or EasyRes. However those software do not list a 1920x1080 resolution on the M1 silicon version.

Comment: you're recording in a higher res. Why not just use that? Otherwise you could just convert the video and rescale it.

Comment: The video needs to be in 16:9 ratio. The MacBook screen has another ratio. Therefore, if I record under the default Mac resolution, the video will end up with black bezels on the sides.

Comment: 16" M1 MBP have 3456 x 2234 res. Just use QuickTime to record 3456 x 1944.